# No Route matches show, missing required keys: [:id]

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have created a task model, everything works except when I go to delete the task.  Also something strange that happens, even though there are no tasks in the database, the @plant.tasks.length is still 1.

_task.html.erb

```
<%= link_to 'MARK COMPLETED', plant_task_path(@plant, task), method: :delete %>
```

Here is the code from my plant show

```
<div class="col-md-4">
  <div class="jumbotron">

    <%= render 'tasks/form' %>
    <% if @plant.tasks.length != 0 %>

        <%= render @plant.tasks %>

    <% end %>
    <%= @plant.tasks.length %>

  </div>
</div>
```

Form for creating the task:

```
form_for([@plant, @plant.tasks.build])
```

My Routes:

```
resources :plants do
  resources :tasks
```

Rake Routes:

```
complete_plant_task PATCH  /plants/:plant_id/tasks/:id/complete(.:format) tasks#complete
    plant_tasks GET    /plants/:plant_id/tasks(.:format)              tasks#index
                POST   /plants/:plant_id/tasks(.:format)              tasks#create
 new_plant_task GET    /plants/:plant_id/tasks/new(.:format)          tasks#new
edit_plant_task GET    /plants/:plant_id/tasks/:id/edit(.:format)     tasks#edit
     plant_task GET    /plants/:plant_id/tasks/:id(.:format)          tasks#show
                PATCH  /plants/:plant_id/tasks/:id(.:format)          tasks#update
                PUT    /plants/:plant_id/tasks/:id(.:format)          tasks#update
                DELETE /plants/:plant_id/tasks/:id(.:format)          tasks#destroy
```

My tasks controller

```
def create
  @task = @plant.tasks.create(task_params)
  redirect_to @plant
end


private 
def set_plant
  @plant = Plant.find(params[:plant_id])
end

def set_task
  @task = @plant.tasks.find(params[:id])
end
```

Im getting this for my trace

```
app/views/tasks/_task.html.erb:7:in `_app_views_tasks__task_html_erb__1645613233755040561_70222907197480'
app/views/plants/show.html.erb:82:in `_app_views_plants_show_html_erb__4438670005226416605_70222868774180'


actionpack (4.2.6) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:259:in `raise_generation_error'
actionpack (4.2.6) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:234:in `optimized_helper'
actionpack (4.2.6) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:220:in `call'
actionpack (4.2.6) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:345:in `block (2 levels) in define_url_helper'
app/views/tasks/_task.html.erb:7:in `_app_views_tasks__task_html_erb__1645613233755040561_70222907197480'
actionview (4.2.6) lib/action_view/template.rb:145:in `block in render'
activesupport (4.2.6) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:166:in `instrument'
```

Ive been up all night trying to figure this out.  Can anyone help me figure this out? Much thanks

Comment: Tip: Use `@plant.tasks.any?` to see if there's any records to display. Also avoid using `id` in `_path` methods, the `to_param` method can be re-written and it's important to leave that up to the URL rendering function. `plant_task_path(@plant, task)` should be sufficient here.

Comment: Does `rake routes` show the correct `plant_task` route?

Comment: can you check if you set up the associations properly

Comment: My associations are set up correctly.  plant has_many tasks task belongs _to plant

Comment: And yes, I do have a plant_task_path in my routes

Comment: When does this error get raised? When doing the delete, when rendering the content that allows the delete, some other time? What does the backtrace of the error look like?

Comment: app/views/tasks/_task.html.erb:7:in `_app_views_tasks__task_html_erb__1645613233755040561_70222907197480'
app/views/plants/show.html.erb:82:in `_app_views_plants_show_html_erb__4438670005226416605_70222868774180'

Comment: When you quoted `<%= link_to 'MARK COMPLETED', plant_task_path(@plant, task), method: :delete %>` - is that from your `_task.html.erb`? Also, is there any code in the `show` method of your controller?

Comment: Yes it is from my _task.html.erb file.  and no there is no code in my show method.  When I enter: url.com/plants/1/tasks, the error I get is 

Couldn't find Task without an ID on my set_plant method

Comment: Assuming nested routes as shown, then `/plants/1/tasks` should be going to the `index` method of `TasksController`, not the `show` method of `PlantsController`.. is that not the case?

Comment: Yes, it should be going to index.  
plant_tasks GET    /plants/:plant_id/tasks(.:format)              tasks#index

Comment: "Missing required keys" means your are not giving a required parameter. What are your required parameters? Ate they named correctly? Would you kindly edit your question posting the line where you require your parameters? I noticed you use **:plant_id** and **:id** in two different methods.

Comment: im not sure exactly how to answer that.  i have plant_id and task_id that i use

Comment: What are the parameters you enforce in your declaration of required parameters?

Comment: Ok. Now let's see the result of **rake routes** in the console. It says **no routes match show** then it is important that we check the existence of such route. Post the result of **rake routes**, please.

Comment: ok, re-edited the post to show the rake routes for tasks.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/110822/discussion-between-ed-de-almeida-and-mgarsteck).